# change value of "Idle connection timeout" on MAC OS

Tags: timeout

it is possible to adapt the "Idle connection timeout" on MAC OS?
If yes. Please describe me how I can do that?

BR.
M.L

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean on an SSH session? you don't make it clear at all what you're actually doing, or on what version of OSX.

If so just edit these values in /etc/sshd_config and restart sshd, this'll change it for everyone.

```
#ClientAliveInterval XXX
#ClientAliveCountMax YYY
```

If you meant something else you're going to have to learn to be much clearer.